# C# Enemy doesn't follow player in Windows Form (not XNA)

Tags: c#, sprite

### **UPDATE**

*I managed to figure the answer out myself, what was happening was that my movement function was only registering the players original static position instead of the dynamic coordinates as the player moved around the screen. What I did was create a 'God' class to publicly store the players current X and Y coordinates, and then reference the 'god' class coordinates in my enemy's movement function.*

*Now, not only does the enemy detect when the player is within it's sights, it will follow the player changing directions accordingly, until it can't 'see' them anymore :D*

*If anyone wants to see the updated code just ask :)*

I'm trying to make a program that contains player and enemy sprites, but I'm having a little trouble with the code for the 'Enemy'. Most of the coding problems on here deal with XNA, which I'm not using, so I was wondering if I could have a little help.

Basically, when the player moves within a certain distance, the movement function for the enemy should activate and it will move towards the players location as long as they're in the 'detection zone'. The enemy's sprite also has a walk animation for each direction, and it should flip through frames depending on whether it's currently moving or not.

The movement function is within a timer, so that it'll update with every tick. I have two separate functions for updating its location, one to physically change it's coordinates in the Form based on the data received from the movement function, and another to update the current frame from my sprite sheet.

The problem is that the enemy doesn't move whatsoever, if I get rid of it's detection and the code to follow the player, and instead just move it across the screen, it works perfectly fine. But unfortunately that's not what I'm trying to achieve.

The code works perfectly fine for my player sprite (albeit, it's controlled by the user and the keyboard keys), so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I believe the problems lies within the Movement function, but I'm not sure what that problem is exactly.

Here's my code for the relevant functions:

```
public void Movement() //This function is in a timer, and determines which direction the sprite will move and face
    {
        //The sprite rectangle is the position of the player sprite, and detection is the area where the enemy would 'see' the player if they entered it
        sprite = new Rectangle(charX - 1, charY + 1, charWidth * 2 + 2, charHeight * 2 + 2);
        Detection = new Rectangle(curX - 25, curY - 25, Enemy.Width * 6, Enemy.Height * 6);

        if (Detection.IntersectsWith(sprite)) //Checks to see if the player is within range
        {
              //Moves the enemy based on the players position and changes direction accordingly
            if (curX > charX) 
            {
                curDirection = RIGHT;
                dX = -1;
                dY = 0;
                numUpdates = 0;
                curAnimation = MOVING;
            }
            else if (curX < charX)
            {
                curDirection = LEFT;
                dX = 1;
                dY = 0;
                numUpdates = 0;
                curAnimation = MOVING;
            }

            if (curY > charY)
            {
                curDirection = UP;
                dY = -1;
                dX = 0;
                numUpdates = 0;
                curAnimation = MOVING;
            }
            else if (curY < charY)
            {
                curDirection = DOWN;
                dY = 1;
                dX = 0;
                numUpdates = 0;
                curAnimation = MOVING;
            }
        }
           //If not within range, don't move the sprite
        else
        {
            dY = 0;
            dX = 0;
            curAnimation = FINISHED;
        }     
    }
```

These are the updating functions that move the enemy and change the current frame

```
        public void Follow() //Physcially moves the enemy across the form
    {         

        int xMod = 0;
        int yMod = 0;

        if (dX != 0)
            xMod = dX / Math.Abs(dX) * 2;

        if (dY != 0)
            yMod = dY / Math.Abs(dY) * 2;


        //Moves the sprite across the x and y axis
        curX += xMod;
        dX += -xMod;

        curY += yMod;
        dY += -yMod;

    }

       public void UpdateFrame(int direction = DOWN)
    {
        numUpdates++;

        switch (curAnimation)
        {
            //Stops the animation if the sprite stops moving
            case FINISHED:
                curFrame = 0;
                break;

            //Moves to the next frame when movement is found
            case MOVING:
                curFrame = (curFrame + 1) % 3;
                Follow();

                //check if done animation
                if (dX == 0 && dY == 0) curAnimation = FINISHED;
                break;
        }
    }
```

If you need more code just ask, any help is appreciated :)

Comment: in order to save yourself time as well as others whom may look at the code, since it's on your machine; have you tried debugging and stepping thru to see if you can pinpoint where you think the problem or issue is occurring ..?

Comment: The most I was able to find is that the problem is somewhere in the 'Movement' function, as changing it's code to just move the enemy in one direction works fine, but I'm not too sure how I would be able to change it to get the results I want

Comment: once again can you explain further what you are expecting and what do you mean when you state that `how would I be able to change it to get the results I want` when we don't know what you want..make sense..?

Comment: Ah, sorry. What I meant is that in the movement function, I want my 'Enemy' to be able to detect whether or not the player is within a certain range (about 10 pixels around the enemy sprite), then if they are, I want the enemy to continuously move towards the players location while they are still within the enemies range. If the player is not within range, then the enemy doesn't move. The current code in my Movement function doesn't work, and my enemy won't move under any circumstance. So what I'm wondering is what exactly am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: without knowing your code I would do the following based on what you said.. 1. maintain enemy position, maintain static or dynamic position of the non-enemy, 2. have a rolling / polling function that checks and compares then issue enemy movement or not based on the enemy's position relative to the pixels of the non-enemy

Comment: That's what my function should be doing, but it's not, that's why I posted this question :/